# unable to get HttpResponse while using HttpClient in login page

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient, http-get

I am trying to perform login based on webservice url.

i am using `HttpClient`,`HttpGet`,`HttpPost` for passing headers to the weburl.
i am using the following code

```
public String postData(String user, String pwd) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://comenius-api.sabacloud.com/v1/login");
        httpPost.addHeader("user",user);
        httpPost.addHeader("password",pwd);
        BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("user", user);
        BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("password", pwd);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
            httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

the above code what i have written to pass the headers to the webservice link.
but the response data i get is an error.

Here is the error i'm getting

```
{"errorCode":99999,"errorMessage":"IncorrectURL,querystring param or http method used when Invoking REST API : null"}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: is your webservice contains query parameter? if yes then only use BasicNameValuePair

Comment: no bro ,i want to pass the headers (user,password) to the weburl ,and the response is to be json data.   i am new to this concept how to fix this.

Comment: ok then remove BasicNameValuePair and keep your headers